# CasperJS not confirming dialog

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

Using casperjs 1.1.4 with slimerjs 1.0.0-beta1 and Firefox 58.0b11.

I have the following code:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.setFilter(
        'page.confirm',
        function(msg) {
            return true;
        },
    );
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        const $btn = $('#btn');
        $btn.click();
    });
});
casper.then(function() {
    test.assertUrlMatch(
        /www.google.com/,
        'Success',
    );
});
```

The confirm dialog appears after clicking on the button. However, for some reason the confirm dialog is never actually confirmed even though I return true all the time.

Comment: In a desperate attempt to get this working I added `casper.wait(1000)` after the click and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for a new resource e.g. a button clickit is always good practice to use a [casper.waitForUrl](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforurl)

In your case something like:

```
casper.waitForUrl("google.com", function() {
    test.assertUrlMatch(
        /www.google.com/,
        'Success',
    );
});
```

See all the [wait for](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) api methods